# Validar múltiple con Javascript

Tags: javascript

En un `select` elijo un producto (Pizza) de tamaño Big (Pizzas cuadradas), cuando elijo el tamaño big se cargan 4 `select` (ahí no tengo problema), el asunto es que, como es una pizza cuadrada pues se pueden elegir especialidades para cada cuadro de la pizza y en las especialidades tengo del grupo1, grupo2 y grupo3.

Necesito validar si todos los segmentos de la pizza son del grupo uno, el precio es de 240, pero si uno de los cuadros es de grupo 2, tengo que increnmentar a esos 240, 40 pesos mas por cada cuadro que elijan del grupo 2 e incluso si algun cuadro es del grupo 3 se incrementa 50 pesos mas.

Por ejemplo un pedido de pizza big donde eligieron Primer cuadro(grupo1), Segundo cuadro(grupo1), Tercer cuadro(grupo2) y cuarto cuadro(Grupo3) = 240 + 40 + 50 = 330

Lo intenté con if anidados.

```
function validar_big(){
    //Array con los grupos 2 y 3
    var grupo2 = ["camaron","pulpo"];
    var grupo3 = ["maxmar"];

    //tomo los valores que eligan en los select
    var c1 = $("#sec1").val();
    var c2 = $("#sec2").val();
    var c3 = $("#sec3").val();
    var c4 = $("#sec4").val();


    //
    var total;
    var neto;

    //Total normal de la pizza big si son del grupo 1
    total = 245;

    //Aqui debe ir la validacion donde si una de las 4 especialidades son del grupo
    //2 o del grupo 3 debe incrementarse en el neto a pagar
    if (grupo3.includes(seg1)) {
        if (grupo3.includes(seg2)) {
            if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                    neto = total + 200;
                    $("#precio").val(neto);
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto); 
                    }else{
                        neto = total + 150;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 150;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 100;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (grupo2.includes(seg2)) {
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2,includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 170;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 90;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 150;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 100;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 90;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 100;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 50;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        if (grupo2.includes(seg1)) {
            if (grupo3.includes(seg2)) {
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto); 
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 170;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto); 
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 90;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 180;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 170;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 170;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 160;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 120;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 120;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 140;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 90;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 120;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 90;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 40;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}





if (grupo3.includes(seg1)) {
        if (grupo3.includes(seg2)) {
            if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                    neto = total + 200;
                    $("#precio").val(neto);
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto); 
                    }else{
                        neto = total + 150;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 150;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 100;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (grupo2.includes(seg2)) {
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2,includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 170;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 90;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 150;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 100;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 90;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 100;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 50;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        if (grupo2.includes(seg1)) {
            if (grupo3.includes(seg2)) {
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 190;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 180;
                            $("#precio").val(neto); 
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 170;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 140;
                            $("#precio").val(neto); 
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 130;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 90;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 180;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 170;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 170;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 160;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 120;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 120;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if (grupo3.includes(seg3)) {
                    if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                        neto = total + 140;
                        $("#precio").val(neto);
                    }else{
                        if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            neto = total + 90;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    if (grupo2.includes(seg3)) {
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 130;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 120;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }else{
                        if (grupo3.includes(seg4)) {
                            neto = total + 90;
                            $("#precio").val(neto);
                        }else{
                            if (grupo2.includes(seg4)) {
                                neto = total + 80;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }else{
                                neto = total + 40;
                                $("#precio").val(neto);
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comparte tu código , para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No pongas capturas de pantalla, por favor. Deberías leerte la ayuda de bienvenida a la comunidad y [esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869)

Comment: podemos ver tus ifs anidados???

Comment: Nadie te ayudara así, no respondes comentarios, el código incompleto, aqui nadie te hara ninguna tarea..

Comment: Hola buen día antes que nada una disculpa a todos, efectivamente solo postie mi pregunta y no me di tiempo de leer las normas y aclaro me disculpo por ello y para nada pretendo que me resuelvan mi tarea por que no es tarea es un problema en un proyecto pero repito, No fue mi intencion faltar a las normas

Comment: SI aun me permiten postear mis mil if anidados jajajaj aqui lo dejo

Comment: Aun no leo las normas y es que mi codigo tiene muchisimas lineas de codigo y no puedo pegarlas aqui entonces dejo un enlace al archivo https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjnBubQHDzH-jKdVP7RNZ65p0k7O1Q